# Double threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to do double threading. Something like:

```
for wordToScan in wordsList:
#...some code
    for i in range(10):
        i_thread = Thread(target=words_Scan_Start, args=(dictionaryFile, wordToScan))
        i_thread.start()

def words_Scan_Start(dictionaryFile, wordToScan):
    # Here I need to make an action with "wordToScan".
    # But in 10 threads "range(10)" and use the same "dictionaryFile" for every thread.
    #...............
```

This means: I am trying to do something in 10 threads simultaneously with every `wordToScan`. But to the same `dictionaryFile`.

In `range(10):` do something for every next item until the end of file/list. But simultaneously for every `wordToScan in wordsList:` using the same `dictionaryFile`.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Also, what does "simultaneously" mean to you, python threads don't offer any guarantees of "simultaneousness".

Comment: If not "simultaneously", then let's omit that notion. In a way that Python can do Treading.

Question about how to make every 10 threads working with one file/list at a time when another 10 threads are working with the same file. But every of 10 thread should iterate through file without reps of line(something like readline()).

Comment: Take a look at `multiprocessing.Pool` and specifically the `map` method of the pool. You could also use a `Queue`, but it sounds like `multiprocessing` is more appropriate for your task (it's hard to know for sure without more info).

Comment: The overhead of starting up a bunch of tiny little threads is going to cost you a lot more than you save. (This is one of the advantages of having a pool, which retains and reuses threads -- or processes, as the case may be -- to perform multiple functions each).

Comment: OTOH, if you're doing heavy IO -- scanning the file once per word, as your description implies -- then frankly, you'd get a bigger performance improvement by using an algorithm that prevents you from needing to do that (storing content in an indexed data structure in memory) than by parallelizing.

Comment: If you're not using something like a `Queue` which is multithreading-safe, you need to use a `Lock` (or `RLock`) to control concurrent access to the shared object (`dictionaryFile` in this case). However there will likely be no benefit in doing this because of the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) and the way Python multithreading works.

Comment: No, there isn't any problem of using Threads or locking some "thread-unsafe" shared resources. But the problem appears, when I'm trying to iterate through the file. I read the file using readline(). That means every thread read new line and pointing cursor on the next line in file. This is what I needed. But when the same is trying to do another `wordToScan in wordsList:`, there are problems begin. Because they use the same `dictionaryFile` as another 10 threads. I need just to make `dictionaryFile.seek(0)` but separately for every 10 threads from `wordToScan in wordsList:`

Comment: What if one thread is in the middle of using `readline()` and another comes along and tries to do the same thing before the it's finished  completing all necessary operations to accomplish this? That's why you need a `Lock` to use to acquire exclusive access to the shared object—it's a basic concurrent programming technique.

Comment: I have already written that I am using Lock() everywhere where it's needed =)